# Solve matrix multiplication problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve this matrix multiplication:

$
\frac{1}{2}\bigl(x_1\ x_2\bigl) \biggl( \begin{matrix} 3 & 1 \\  1 & 2 \\ \end{matrix} \biggl) \biggl( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\  x_2  \\ \end{matrix} \biggl)$

I got the following answer. Is this correct?

$ {2x_1}^2 + \frac{3}{2}\ {x_2}^2$

Comment: No, it isn't correct.

Comment: you're missing $+x_1x_2$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you can check your computation easily on any platform, e.g., Wolfram Alpha. As written, it's an isolated problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get $\frac{3}{2}x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + \frac{1}{2}x_2^2$.

Comment: I get $\frac32x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2$